# What's the difference between resolve(thenable) and resolve('non-thenable-object')?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I was trying to understand the difference between `resolve(thenable)` and `resolve('non-thenable-object')`.

In examples below, use promise instead of `thenable` because promise is also `thenable` and may be easier to understand.

#### Demo1: `resolve(promise)`

```js
let resolvePromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  let resolvedPromise = Promise.resolve()
  resolve(resolvedPromise)
})
resolvePromise.then(() => {
  console.log('resolvePromise resolved')
})
let resolvedPromiseThen = Promise.resolve().then(res => {
  console.log('promise1')
})
resolvedPromiseThen
  .then(() => {
    console.log('promise2')
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('promise3')
  })
```

**result:**

- promise1
- promise2
- resolvePromise resolved
- promise3

#### Demo2: `resolve('non-thenable-object')`

```js
let resolvePromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  resolve('non-thenable-object')
})
resolvePromise.then(() => {
  console.log('resolvePromise resolved')
})
let resolvedPromiseThen = Promise.resolve().then(res => {
  console.log('promise1')
})
resolvedPromiseThen
  .then(() => {
    console.log('promise2')
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('promise3')
  })
```

**result:**

- resolvePromise resolved
- promise1
- promise2
- promise3

So, I checked the spec and found [Promise Resolve Functions](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise-resolve-functions)
. Then got to [PromiseResolveThenableJob](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promiseresolvethenablejob) and [EnqueueJob](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-enqueuejob).

So, according to the spec, I think **demo1** was like

#### Demo3:

```js
let resolvePromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  let resolvedPromise = Promise.resolve()
 // resolve(resolvedPromise)
  // works like 
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    Promise.resolve(resolvedPromise).then(() => {
      resolve()
   })
  })
})
resolvePromise.then(() => {
  console.log('resolvePromise resolved')
})
let resolvedPromiseThen = Promise.resolve().then(res => {
  console.log('promise1')
})
resolvedPromiseThen
  .then(() => {
    console.log('promise2')
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('promise3')
  })
```

I think so because [Promise Resolve Functions](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise-resolve-functions) says:

> 13. Perform EnqueueJob("PromiseJobs", PromiseResolveThenableJob, « promise, resolution, thenAction »).

And [PromiseResolveThenableJob](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promiseresolvethenablejob) says:

> This Job uses the supplied thenable and its then method to resolve the given promise. **This process must take place as a Job to ensure that the evaluation of the then method occurs after evaluation of any surrounding code has completed.**

Also, I think **demo2** works like

#### Demo4:

```js
//let resolvePromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  //resolve('str')
//})
//works like
let resolvePromise = Promise.resolve('str')

resolvePromise.then(() => {
  console.log('resolvePromise resolved')
})
let resolvedPromiseThen = Promise.resolve().then(res => {
  console.log('promise1')
})

resolvedPromiseThen
  .then(() => {
    console.log('promise2')
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('promise3')
  })
```

As the [Promise Resolve Functions](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise-resolve-functions) says:

> If IsCallable(thenAction) is false, then Return FulfillPromise(promise, resolution).

Though the results between **Demo1**-**Demo3** and **Demo2**-**Demo4** are equal, I am still not sure if I was right. So, I am here to ask

**whether my logic is right? If not, how do you explain the different orders 
 between `resolve(thenable)` and `resolve(non-thenable)` ?**

Comment: I recommend in general to never rely on callback invocation order between unrelated promises. Although the spec gives a specific queuing semantic, it should never be relevant in practice. If you need a specific order because your callbacks depend on each other, be explicit about that by chaining your promises after each other.

Comment: @Bergi, Actually, in practice, I always use promises chain to control the async order. But I really want to understand the spec and principle.

Comment: Upvoted for the comment. Nothing is wrong with genuine interest in understanding the specification for the sake of understanding, even if it's not good to rely on in practice.

Answer (score 3):

After reading the specification and testing many times I thought I might get it.

Before we start, we have to settle something.

let's call it `RESOLVE()` when using `resolve` in `Promise executor`. For example, `RESOLVE(thenable)` means the code like:

```
  new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    resolve(thenable)
  })
```

while `resolve(thenable)` means `Promise.resolve(thenable)`

Ok, let's begin.

#### `Promise.resolve('non-thenable')` and `RESOLVE('non-thenable')`

When we are using `Promise.resolve('non-thenable')` it comes to [Promise.resolve](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise.resolve)

[image]

Then it comes to [PromiseResolve](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise-resolve)

[image]

That's the where `Promise.resolve('non-thenable')` was transformed to

```
new Promise(resolve=>{
  resolve('non-thenable')
})
```

So, we have the conclusion:

> `Promise.resolve('non-thenable')` can be transformed into `RESOLVE('non-thenable')`

---

#### `RESOLVE(thenable)`

**demo1**

```js
let resolveThenable = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let thenable = {
    then: function (resolve, reject) {
      console.log('in thenable')
      resolve(42)
    }
  }
  resolve(thenable)
  // works like
  // Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  //   thenable.then(resolve)
  // })
  // should be ?
  // Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  //   thenable.then.[[Value]](resolve)
  // })
  // equivalent to?
  // Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  //   thenable.then(resolve)
  // })
})
resolveThenable.then(() => {
  console.log('resolveThenable resolved')
})
let resolvedPromiseThen = Promise.resolve().then(res => {
  console.log('promise1')
})
resolvedPromiseThen
  .then(() => {
    console.log('promise2')
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('promise3')
  })

// 'in thenable'
// 'promise1'
// 'resolveThenable resolved'
// 'promise2'
// 'promise3'
```

According to [Promise Resolve Functions](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise-resolve-functions), when we were using `RESOLVE(thenable)` it comes to

[image]

Then it comes to [PromiseResolveThenableJob](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promiseresolvethenablejob)

[image]

This would make `RESOLVE(thenable)` works like

```
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    thenable.then.[[Value]](resolve)
  })
```

So, I thought it is equivalent to

```
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    thenable.then(resolve)
  })
```

Which got the same result as `RESOLVE(thenable)`.

> So, we can say `RESOLVE(thenable)` can be transformed to

```
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    thenable.then(resolve)
  })
```

demo2

```js
let resolvePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let resolvedPromise = Promise.resolve()
  resolve(resolvedPromise)
  // works like
  // Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  //   resolvedPromise.then(() => {
  //     resolve()
  //   })
  // })
  // should be?
  // Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  //   resolvedPromise.then.[[Value]](resolve,reject)
  // })
  // equivalent to ?
  // Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  //   resolvedPromise.then(resolve)
  // })
  // equivalent to ?
  // Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  //   resolvedPromise.then(() => {
  //     resolve()
  //   })
  // })
})
resolvePromise.then(() => {
  console.log('resolvePromise resolved')
})
let resolvedPromiseThen = Promise.resolve().then(res => {
  console.log('promise1')
})
resolvedPromiseThen
  .then(() => {
    console.log('promise2')
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('promise3')
  })

// 'promise1'
// 'promise2'
// 'resolvePromise resolved'
// 'promise3'
```

When we talked about `RESOLVE(resolvedPromise)`, we can find the spec doesn't distinguish `thenable` from `promise`. So, in the same way, `RESOLVE(resolvedPromise)` can be transformed into

```
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    resolvedPromise.then(resolve)
  })
```

Though, in this case, the order between `RESOLVE(thenable)` and `RESOLVE(promise)` is different. Because `thenable.then` is a sync operation while `resolvedPromise.then` is an async operation. They are not the same `then` method.

So, here is our conclusion:

> Both `RESOLVE(thenable)` and `RESOLVE(promise)` can be transformed into

```
 new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        thenable.then(resolve)
      })
 })
```

---

#### Promise.resolve(thenable)

It is quite simple when using `Promise.resolve(promise)` because it returns `promise` argument.

However, things become complicated when using `Promise.resolve(thenable)` and the `thenable` is not a promise. Let's call it `Promise.resolve(nonPromiseThenable)`.

According to [Promise.resolve ( x )](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise.resolve)

[image]

Then it comes to

[image]

So, `Promise.resolve(nonPromiseThenable)` can be transformed to

```
 new Promise(resolve => { 
   resolve(nonPromiseThenable)
 })
```

And finally comes to

```
 new Promise(resolve => { 
   Promise.resolve().then(() => { 
     nonPromiseThenable.then(resolve) 
   }) 
 })
```

You can test it in the demo below.

```js
var thenable = {
  then(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(1)
  }
}
// code transformation 
Promise.resolve(thenable).then(res => {
  console.log(res)
})
// equal 
// new Promise(resolve => { 
//   resolve(thenable) 
// }).then(res => { 
//   console.log(res) 
// }) 
// equal 
// new Promise(resolve => { 
//   Promise.resolve().then(() => { 
//     thenable.then(resolve) 
//   }) 
// }).then(res => { 
//   console.log(res) 
// }) 

new Promise(resolve => resolve(2))
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
  .then(res => console.log(3))
```

**In the end, let's make a conclusion:**

- `Promise.resolve('nonThenable')` can be transformed into `RESOLVE('nonThenable')`. They have the same effects.
- `Promise.resolve(thenable)` is different from `RESOLVE(thenable)`. They have different effects.
- `RESOLVE(thenable)` and `RESOLVE(promise)`  can be transformed into

  `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      thenable.then(resolve)
    })
  })`
- `Promise.resolve(promise) === promise` while `Promise.resolve(nonPromiseThenable)` can be transformed into

  `new Promise(resolve => { 
     Promise.resolve().then(() => { 
       nonPromiseThenable.then(resolve) 
     }) 
   })`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your logic looks right.

`new Promise(resolve => resolve('non-thenable-object'))` is equivalent to `Promise.resolve('non-thenable-object')` for all purposes.

In your Demo3 I would however recommend to leave out `Promise.resolve(resolvedPromise)`. I'm not sure whether that was intentional or not, but `Promise.resolve` does have a shortcut when its argument is already a promise, and then returns the `resolvedPromise` as-is. You'd rather write

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let resolvedPromise = Promise.resolve();
  // resolve(resolvedPromise) works like 
  Promise.resolve().then(() => resolvedPromise.then(resolve, reject));
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/xianshenglu/blog/issues/60#issuecomment-449739628 Can you explain the `resolveThenable` example? Feels like work in a different way between resolve(thenable) and resolve(promise)

Comment: No, thenables and promises are treated exactly the same (namely, as thenables) by `resolve`. What is unexpected? Notice that your `thenable´ calls the "onfulfilled" callback synchrously (not asynchronously like a real promise), so that might affect ordering.